# How to connect a 3G USB dongle with Windows Mobile 6 emulator?

Tags: windows-mobile, serial-port, emulation, gprs

I have a real 3G USB dongle which shows several Serial ports. I want to map one of the Serial ports of the Windows Mobile emulator serial ports to the real device, to test a custom RIL implementation.

First, is this scenario possible?

I have tried to modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\RIL\ComPort` on the WM emulator, to set up COM1. I have also tried to map the emulator serial ports to the real device.

Using a serial port monitor, what I can see is just how the serial port is open, and no data is transferred. RTS and DTR lights are "on" on the monitor. Could it be a configuration problem of the serial port? Do anyone know the configuration of the Windows Mobile emulator serial ports?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can map two emulator ports to two real serial ports. See this article for [details](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/38500). The ports will appear as standard serial ports. If your dongle offers some extra functionality, it will not be available.

Comment: You are correct, but I've already tried that. The emulator correctly opens the mapped serial port, but the data does not move between them. If I use the Cellular emulator (as detailed in you article), it works fine. The problem seems to be about the configuration between both sides (parity, baud speed, etc...) but I don't know the exact config of the emulator serial port. Thanks, anyway, for you answer :)